# How to validate NFS Snapshot image

Tags: unix, nfs, shell-scripting

I am writing a small shell script which will validate the NFS backup by looking into the snapshot and checking the contents of one directory to make sure the correct contents are being backed up.

CreateTestFile.sh - this will create file backupchecker.txt a directory with date
ValidateNFSBackup.sh - this will validate the backup by looking for this backupchecker.txt content.

Am I going in right direction?

Appreciate your time.

Comment: It's a bit confused. Are you backuping just content of single directory? If yes, just run "cd <directory> && md5sum * > /tmp/<directory name>.md5". Then copy the md5 file to the backup location and run "md5sum -c <directory_name>.md5" The best if you do that on the remote server, otherwise you'd have to transfer all data over the network again (bacause of NFS). Or avoid using NFS and use rsync instead.

Comment: I find hard to understand what you're asking. What's the purpose of mentioning this custom shell scripts omitting the code? What help would you expect if we don't know what your scripts actually do?

Comment: @JaroslavKucera - just one directory